# Split NSString by number of whitespaces

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSString` that contains some values separated by an unknown number of whitespace characters. For example:

```
NSString* line = @"1 2     3";
```

I would like to split the `NSString` into an `NSArray` of values like so: `{@"1", @"2", @"3"}`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get the components separated by `@" "` and remove all objects like `@""` from the resultant array.

```
NSString* line = @"1 2     3";
NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[line componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
[array removeObject:@""]; // This removes all objects like @""
```

Comment: Interesting; I didn't realise `removeObject` removed *all* occurrences. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: Chris Doble, Chris Ledet, Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick (assuming the values don't contain whitespace):

```
// Gives us [@"1", @"2", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"3"].
NSArray *values = [line componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

// Remove the empty strings.
values = [values filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];
```