# Take all numbers separated by spaces from a string and place in an array

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSString formatted like this:

> "Hello world 12 looking for some 56"

I want to find all instances of numbers separated by whitespace and place them in an NSArray. I dont want to remove the numbers though.

Whats the best way of achieving this?

Comment: regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using `regular expression` as suggested in the comment.

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world 12 looking for some 56";

NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b\\d+" options:nil error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [expression matchesInString:string options:nil range:(NSMakeRange(0, string.length))];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  [result addObject:[string substringWithRange:match.range]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make an array using NSString's [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) method and take reference to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537210). Then iterate the array and refer to this SO question to check if an array element is number: [Checking if NSString is Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238221/checking-if-nsstring-is-integer).

Comment: Im currently using  NSArray *a = [self.textparagraph componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];  which splits via the number, Basically the numbers in the text delineate delay length for AVSpeechSynth. Each number encountered is also treated as a new line so I can insert pauses . This works fine but I need to know the number values that its discarding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are looking to do perform this action because it may not be fast (such as if it's being called in a table cell it may be choppy) based upon the string size.

**Code:**

```
+ (NSArray *)getNumbersFromString:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableArray *retVal = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSCharacterSet *numericSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    NSString *placeholder = @"";
    unichar currentChar;
    for (int i = [str length] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentChar = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([numericSet characterIsMember:currentChar]) {
            placeholder = [placeholder stringByAppendingString: 
                                [NSString stringWithCharacters:&currentChar 
                                                        length:[placeholder length]+1];
        } else {
            if ([placeholder length] > 0) [retVal addObject:[placeholder intValue]];
            else placeholder = @"";

    return [retVal copy];
}
```

To explain what is happening above, essentially I am,

- going through every character until I find a number
- adding that number including any numbers after to a string
- once it finds a number it adds it to an array

Hope this helps please ask for clarification if needed